# How can I fetch from multi level array in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, group-by, eloquent

My question is about fetching data from multi level array what is generated from Laravel Groupby method ( Eloquent) .

-array

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
    4 => array:1 [▼
      2 => array:7 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▶]
        1 => array:7 [▶]
        2 => array:7 [▶]
        3 => array:7 [▶]
        4 => array:7 [▶]
        5 => array:7 [▶]
        6 => array:7 [▶]
      ]
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
      1 => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▶]
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      1 => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:7 [▶]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Actually my datatable is so-

```
{
  "2": {
    "1": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 7,
        "session_id": 2,
        "semester_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:18:27",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:18:27"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3": {
    "1": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 1,
        "session_id": 3,
        "semester_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:18:27",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:18:27"
      }
    ]
  },
  "4": {
    "2": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 20,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 23,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 24,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 45,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 46,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 47,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "technology_id": 1,
        "subject_id": 48,
        "session_id": 4,
        "semester_id": 2,
        "created_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49",
        "updated_at": "2019-01-18 18:16:49"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect view in html is so-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/90t3z.jpg

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide some code, what have you tried so far.

Comment: In My Laravel Controller

``` 
$technology_subjects = TechnologySubject::all();

$grouped = $technology_subjects->(['technology_id','session_id','semester_id']);
```